# Could not resolve host: dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus, fiware-cosmos

Trying to upload some measurements to COSMOS. I have an COSMOS account.
Also, I'm using the tutorial here: https://github.com/ging/fiware-cosmos/blob/master/doc/manuals/quick_start_guide_new.md

I'm stuck on Step 3: Upload some data to HDFS.
This is the process flow for me:

```
curl -v -X PUT -T measurements.txt "http://storage.dit.upm.es:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/MY-USERNAME/MY-FOLDER/measurements.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=MY-USERNAME" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "X-Auth-token: MY-ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

After this request, I get the expected response according to the tutorial. But then on the next request...

```
curl -v -X PUT -T measurements.txt "http://dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/MY-USERNAME/MY-FOLDER/measurements.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=MY-USERNAME&data=true" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -H "X-Auth-token: MY-ACCESS-TOKEN"
```

...I get the following response:

`* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
* Could not resolve host: dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es`

Anybody else that has had the same problem?

Comment: Can't open `dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es:14000` here also.

Comment: Not sure... I'm not getting the message "Port failed" or anything like that...

Comment: Did you read the **NOTES:** `dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es is just an alias of storage.dit.upm.es.`. Is it still an alias now?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shihe Zhang for the idea!

Changed `dev-fiwr-svc-01.tid.es:14000` to `storage.dit.upm.es:14000` and my file was uploaded.